# SMB connection with external disk lost

Tags: 16.04, networking, mount, samba

I have a tomcat server in **Ubuntu 16.04** server, in this tomcat server run some webapp.
I created a connection with my `Windows` storage server for the folder of my webapp, the folder on Ubuntu server are under `/home/` directory.

My problem is that randomically the connection with this external folder are lost.

For the connection I had modify the `mtab` file:

```
//SRV-MYSTORAGE/folder-as /home/folderonserver cifs credentials=/etc/samba/cred,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

In these cases I launch the command `sudo mount -a`, which is success once on 4 times.

I don't understand how to resolve problem.

Creating a **cron** with the mount is not a solution that I like..

Have you have any suggestions?